# plt.contourf does not display mask from the numpy.ma.core.MaskedArray I want to plot

Tags: python-3.x

I have interpolated a numpy.ma.core.MaskedArray with scipy.interpolate.griddata and when I want to display it, it doesn't seem to take into account the mask.

I tried different fill_values (because I get indeed a new numpy.ma.core.MaskedArray after interpolated the old one), different methods of displaying my data but the mask seems to be ignored.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.